# <script> tag not working in html <head> or external js file

Tags: jquery, html, onclicklistener, script-tag, external-js

Trying to require js in an HTML file. Required the external js files through the  tags seen below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/events.js"></script>
```

These script tags did not work because the event handlers inside them did not fire. So, in a previous project I had luck writing all the js logic in  tags within the  of the HTML, which looks like this (also in this project along with external js) Also, the html file has a button with "shuffle" as its class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".shuffle").click(function(){
  console.log("hello");
  let arr = onShuffle();
  shuffleSuccess(arr);
});

</script>
```

The interesting thing about this is I put the above function in the console of the index.html/project's file and the click handler worked as well as the `shuffleSuccess` function, which is in the external js file. Thanks!

Comment: If you're putting it in the `<head>`, when it runs there is no element with the `shuffle` class.  Javascript runs at the point it was parsed in the HTML doc.  You need to wrap it in a [onready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event or place it _after_ where the element is defined.

Comment: That's a good point. I have a button with the class="shuffle". Would that work?

Comment: Only if the button is _above_ where that function is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script needs to execute after your button is in the DOM. Your options are to place it at the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag, or use [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) as shown below:

```
//This waits until all objects are loaded in the DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Then assigns the event handler
    $(".shuffle").click(function(){
      console.log("hello");
      let arr = onShuffle();
      shuffleSuccess(arr);
    });
});
```

If your script is in an external file `$(document).ready` is a good option.

**Alternatively**, you could use http://api.jquery.com/on/ . This will apply the click handler to anything with the class `shuffle` that is in the `body`, even if it is added later. This is arguably better than `$(document).ready`

```js
$("body").on("click", ".shuffle", function() {
  console.log("hello");
  /*let arr = onShuffle();
  shuffleSuccess(arr);*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
```

If you want to change your script order, something like the following will work:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Your Page</title>
      <!-- Some CSS Links -->
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- Some Content --> 
     <input type="button" value="I'm a button">
     <!-- Some more content -->
     <!-- Note: the script comes after the button is placed -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".shuffle").click(function(){
        console.log("hello");
        let arr = onShuffle();
        shuffleSuccess(arr);
     });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

**My suggestions are**
**1.**  If you using html5, like <!DOCTYPE html>, then use the following instead:

```html
<script src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/events.js"></script>
```

**2.**  Put the script tags at the bottom of the page like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- include jquery cdn link. internet connection is needed to work-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>  <!-- just some elements -->
            <div>Just some elements</div>
        </div>
        <!-- include the script tags here like this -->
        <script src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/events.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**3.**  Check that you correctly specified the javascript file paths.
Still if all of these didn't solve your problem, you may need to post the actual html and describe the file structure for the html and the javascipt. I almost forgot to ask if jquery is confirmed to be working, did you include link to jquery?

**A few more things** 
**1.**   Please do this before trying out any of the above suggestions:
Comment out all your jquery code and write console.log("Hi");, check if it worked. If it did not work, then use the script tags as above and try again. If it didn't work this time this means you incorrectly specified the js file path.
If it worked, then something is wrong with jquery.